I accidently change my current repo to main rather than pushing to it now all my files are getting reversed
https://github.com/HashirShazad/Parkour_Game
I was trying to merger my current branch to main.
Thank god i deleted all of the changes and reverted back to my bracnh.
addas'df,lajfo hsdlmg;asmg;as;ga]
gkaslkflasd
fasl dflasd
;f
asdlf;lasd
lf
lasd;
fl;asdl;
flasdlf\sadl];flasd]lflasdflasdlfasl CHAR LIMIT><TO OVERCOME THE CHAR LIMIT>

Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you have a question regarding Godot or Git? If so, please state the question clearly and tag it accordingly. Otherwise this post will just get flagged.

You mentioned you had an accident managing your repository, and you said you deleted all the changes and reverted to your branch... So, while I can asasume you want some solution to revert the accident, it also seems you did something about it... Please notice you didn't - at the time of writing - make a single question in your "question". So, to motivate you to share some details... Did the revert you did not solve the issue? Is there still something you want to figure out how to do? Did you have any unexpected result from what you did?

The problem is solved cuz i reverted back the changes and saved my main branch to overwride the current branch. I wanted to merge the 2 branches but accidently did that. I then reverted the changes by going back to current branch and saved all of my code. I would like to tag this question as solved but cant find a way.

Just revert back all the changes. By going back to current branch.
This will save ur code. As when u selected main branch it started overwriting the current, so just revert it
